# Why is the animation not reseting to pre-hover state after 1 sec?

Tags: html, css

I have animation on hover. I want to reset it to pre-hover state after 1 sec. Currently it is animating for 1 sec but stuck in the `to` state of `keyframe`. How to make it go to pre-hover state even without the `mouseout`.

```css
.box:hover {
  --border-size: 3px;
  --border-angle: 0turn;
  background-image: conic-gradient(
  from var(--border-angle),
  #ebe7ee,
  #d7d7ef 50%,
  #fff
),
conic-gradient(from var(--border-angle), transparent 20%, #08f, #f03);
  background-size: calc(100% - (var(--border-size) * 2))
  calc(100% - (var(--border-size) * 2)),
cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  animation: bg-spin 1s linear forwards;
  @keyframes bg-spin {
to {
  --border-angle: 1turn;
}
  }
}

@property --border-angle {
  syntax: "<angle>";
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 0turn;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just switch the **forwards** in your animation property by **backwards**.

Forwards maintains the ending state of the animation while backwards resets it like the beginning of the animation.

```
.box:hover {
  animation: bg-spin 1s linear backwards;
}

@keyframes bg-spin {
   to {
     --border-angle: 1turn;
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution but doesn't do the job. With this change the animation I am seeing is same as what I saw for `forward`. Note on hover I am adding `background-image`, `background-size` etc which all needs to revert back to pre-hover state.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what @hëcalim said is correct, `backwards` is the required trick but to get it working I had to move `background-image` inside `@keyframes` as well so that it is only present for `0%` and not present for `100%`

Here is what the final css code looked like:

```css
.box:hover {
   --border-size: 3px;
   --border-angle: 0turn;
   animation: bg-spin 1s linear backwards;

  @keyframes bg-spin {
    0% {
      background-image:
        conic-gradient(
          from var(--border-angle),
          #ebe7ee,
          #d7d7ef 50%,
          #fff
        ),
        conic-gradient(
          from var(--border-angle),
          transparent 20%,
         #08f,
          #f03
        );
      background-size:
        calc(100% - (var(--border-size) * 2))
        calc(100% - (var(--border-size) * 2)),
        cover;
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    100% {
      --border-angle: 1turn;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix , ; etc i just cut pasted these

```css
.box:hover {
     animation: bg-spin 1s linear forwards;
     @keyframes bg-spin {
        0% {
          --border-size: 1px;
          --border-angle: 0turn;
          background: none;
     }
     50% {
          --border-size: 3px;
          --border-angle: 1turn;
          background-image: conic-gradient(
          from var(--border-angle),
          #ebe7ee,
          #d7d7ef 50%,
          #fff
          ),
         conic-gradient(from var(--border-angle), transparent 20%, #08f, #f03);
         background-size: calc(100% - (var(--border-size) * 2))
      calc(100% - (var(--border-size) * 2)),
    cover;
         background-position: center center;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    100% {
          --border-size: 1px;
          --border-angle: 0turn;
          background: none;
}
      }
    }

    @property --border-angle {
      syntax: "<angle>";
      inherits: true;
      initial-value: 0turn;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```